# Почему может не работать shortcode в acf?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Нужно что бы работали шорткоды в дополнительных полях.
Использую хук с официального сайта.
Но даже после использования этого кода, шорт код не отображается.

```
function my_acf_format_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    // run do_shortcode on all textarea values
    $value = do_shortcode($value);

    // return
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/type=textarea', 'my_acf_format_value', 10, 3);
```

Плагин Advanced Custom Fields PRO

Comment: Что у вас передается в $value, $post_id, $field ? вы уверены что там именно шорткод ?
 Вы уверены что my_acf_format_value вообще срабатывает по хуку?

Comment: Я хочу вставить contact form 7 доп поле, если честно не знаю как отследить, я думал что хук просто позволяет вставлять любые шорт коды.

Comment: do_shortcode - выполняет шорткод а не вставляет его

Comment: @BroouzerKing А как же тогда сделать так что бы в доп поле можно было вставлять шорт коды?

Comment: честно говоря я не очень понимаю что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, разверните пожалуйста вопрос что бы  было понятно какой результат вы хотите получить

Comment: @BroouzerKing https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939437/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89114/discussion-between-broouzer-king-and-andrii-soldatenko).